# QtWebKit Linux Phonon Support Status

Tags: linux, qt, qtwebkit, phonon

Does anybody know what the status of video playback in QtWebKit is?  According to these release notes: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit, it seems like playback is supported (on Nokia phones?) ... I got it to work with some AVI video in Windows but seem to be having problems in Linux.  In Windows the Phonon backend is DirectDraw and it's GStreamer in Linux and I think that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which [gstreamer plugin sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer#Plug-ins) do you have installed? Which ones you need will depend on the codec used to compress your AVI (if any) - [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) is a pretty awesome little app for finding out what codecs you're using.

From the [GStreamer site](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/download/):

> Most, if not all, Linux distributions provide packages of GStreamer.
>   You should find these in your distribution's package repository.  **Note
>   that some distributions split the GStreamer plugins up further than
>   the upstream sources. Additionally, some distributions do not include
>   the gst-plugins-bad, gst-plugins-ugly, and gst-ffmpeg packages in
>   their main repository, for legal reasons.**

Comment: I have gst-base and gst-ffmpeg.  Sorry about the delay in accepting.